# php variable as array key within html form name

Tags: php, html, forms

i need to send some string in form.The form i am creating using foreach loop.like this

```
foreach ($myArray as $key => $workingWith) {
... some work ....
echo '<input type="text" name="title['.$workingWith.']" >';
}
```

but i need the resulting url to look like

```
...php?title["someLiteral"]=someValue&.....
```

important for me are the double quotes.
rewriting both sending and recieving script IS an option , so if im going about this all wrong please tell me so.The recieving script doesnt recognize unquoted key as key,so what solution is best for me ?

Comment: Try this : echo '<input type="text" name="title[\"'.$workingWith.'\"]" >';

Comment: If you are open to alternative solutions then please tell us why you want to do this to give some context.

Comment: the entire script does following : lists pictures in folder , does some resampling and resizing , shows thumbnails and with them the text input , in order to store description for the picture.The description i would handle in the "recieving" script,but would like to have array of descriptions keyed by filenames.

Comment: @vascowhite probably he needs `$_GET['title']` to be an associative array.

Comment: the escaping breaks html unfortunately leaving backslash but not quote